# Trying to find characters that do not resemble Hex in the format '\x0a'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, special-characters

I am parsing a string that contains file magic numbers but the formatting is inconsistent. Some of the patterns are in Hex with the format '\x0a'(Where the string holds an escaped char so I apparently need to search for both \'s), others are the direct ASCII characters and the rest are somewhere in between.

I was hoping to make a Regular Expression to find the characters in a string that are not already Hex. I attempted the following search for Hex values with the inversion flag.

```
(?!\\\\x[0-9 a-f]{2})
```

This did not work as intended as it sees the x in the next character after the full match and matches to that.

```
>>> test = "\\x50K\\x03\\x04"
>>> re.search("(?!\\\\x[0-9 a-f]{2})" test)
<re.Match object; span(1, 1), match=''>
```

Without getting the positive results and inverting them myself I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace hex values with nothing like this:`re.sub(r'\\x[0-9 a-f]{2}','', your_line)` and use what remains -- non-hex characters

Comment: Ok. Based on your suggestion I have made a solution. I don't know whether I should put it in a comment or in a separate answer however